# RichTextBox - AccessibleName

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to improve the Accessibility of a WinForms application.

In doing so, I stumbled across what I think may be a bug in `RichTextBox`.

No matter what I set its `AccessibleName` to, it is read as "Rich Edit control", unless there's a `Label` on the same `Parent`, with a lower `TabIndex` and inserted into the parent's `Controls` collection right before the `RichTextBox`.

While that may be a simple thing to do, why is the `RichTextBox` control ignoring `AccessibleName`? Are there other ways to fix this other than adding a label on the same parent? That's not always an ideal solution.

Comment: `AccessibleName`, as other Accessible properties, belongs to the Control class, not the RichTextBox class. UI Automation returns the `AccessibleName` as the `AutomationElement.Name` property (when `AccessibleName` is set, otherwise what `TextPattern.GetText()` returns). -- `AutomationId` is usually the Name of a Control. You may want to set the `AccessibleDescription` property. --Also, specify the .Net version you're using, when this property is being set and what sets it.

Comment: .NET Version: .NET 4.8. Property is set as the dialog is shown.
Can you elaborate on the `TextPattern` and its relevance in this scenario?
`RichTextBox` *is* a `Control`, so why is it valid to assume that it should follow different rules from everything else?

Comment: Accessibility can be tested with UI Automation. An Automation Element returns all values set by the Accessibility properties: `AccessibleName => AutomationElement.Name`, `AccessibleId => [UI Element Name]`, `HelpText => AccessibleDescription`. You can test what accessibility tools read from your Controls. -- The RichTextBox class doesn't follow any custom rule, since - as mentioned - it doesn't consider accessibility at all. The Control class does, partially based on the `AccessibilityImprovements` Level. The accessible object info is created when a Control creates its handle.

Comment: I don't know what *Property is set as the dialog is shown* means. Nor what *...it is read as "Rich Edit control"* implies: what reads it? Do you have software that deals with accessibility that reads/voices `Rich Edit control`, at some point? The .Net Framework 4.8 RichTextBox Control is not a Win32 Rich Edit class. -- Try to set the `AccessibleDescription` property.

Comment: If the `AccessibleName` property is not set, since the Control class set `ControlStyles.UseTextForAccessibility` in `CreateParams`, the Text of a Control is used as the `AccessibleName`, hence this is what UI Automation returns as the `AutomationElement.Name` property value. MSAA would instead return an empty string as `Name` and the Control's Text as `Value`. Both UI Automation and MSAA read the `AccessibleDescription` Property value the same way.